# navigate to html page within javascript

Tags: javascript, html, confirmation

Have a confirmation window before submitting,  but after returning true(confirm submission) also needs to go to confirmation page.

Have this:

```
<button type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" onclick="clicked();" >Submit Form</button>

function clicked() {
   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit? You will not be able to go back.')) {
       yourformelement.submit();
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Trying to include 'go to' location.href='Confirmation.html' somewhere but unsure exactly how. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form will not be submitted asynchronously as far as I can see. The server will be able to redirect your browser to another page, by replying with a "Location" header to the form submission.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the window.location.href property to manually perform the navigation :

```
window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
```

Or if you are using a form, simply set the action attribute of the  element to "Confirmation.html"

```
<form action='Confirmation.html'>
```

Comment: You are suggesting that he should submit the form to the page where he wants to navigate next?

Comment: I may have misunderstood him slightly in that regard. The window.location.href method is probably all that was needed, otherwise the navigation will need to be handled by the page that is being posted to.

Comment: I will try this but where in my clicked() function do I include window.location.href; Im very new to js

Comment: You would just need to include the line above 'window.location.href = "Confirmation.html"' either before or after your 'yourformelement.submit()' call. Keep in mind that calling submit will likely cause your page to refresh and thus avoid navigating away

Comment: Throws me an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  in console

Comment: function clicked() {
       if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit? You will not be able to go back.')) {
           formelement.submit();
     window.location.href = "Confirmation.html;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
    }

Comment: @user2912336 submitting the form is the same as making an HTTP request. In this moment you are passing over control on the flow of things to the server. If you want to navigate to "Confirmation.html" after you submitted the form, you should not do this yourself in the client, but let the server do this for you.

Comment: @PaulGleeson this is a synchronous submit. If he includes the line before submitting then the form will never be submitted, it will make the document unload. If he includes the line after submitting the line will never be reached or it will produce a broken pipe on the server.

Comment: @mwhs it is just local storage i'm dealing with if that makes a difference

Comment: This alone doesnt even work for me.function clicked(){
 window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = 'new url'
```

Should do the trick.

Edit: misunderstood the question. Would placing a PHP header redirect at the bottom of your form process script work?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the .html file in the public folder and navigate as usual.

For example:

```
href = "public/web.html"
```

worked for me in Nextjs.

Comment: your code blocks should be formatted with ``` and answer needs supporting information